# Constructing the Confusion matrix from given metrics

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I am given the following metrics for a certain classifier : 
 -Total number of cases in the dataset = 110 
 -Accuracy: 92.7%
 -Precision : 96.9%
 -Recall : 95%

Are this information enough to reconstruct the confusion matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[edit thanks to comment] I'm assuming this is a binary classifier, since normally a multi-class classifier would not be evaluated with precision/recall (it would require micro/macro precision/recall).*

Yes, that should be enough:

- accuracy = 92.7%:

$$\frac{TP+TN}{110}=0.927 \rightarrow TP+TN=101.97$$

This means we have 102 correct predictions, so $FP+FN= 8$ incorrect predictions (since $TP+FP+TN+FN=110$).

- precision = 96.9%:

$$\frac{TP}{TP+FP}=0.969 \rightarrow TP=31.258\times FP$$

- recall = 95%:

$$\frac{TP}{TP+FN}=0.950 \rightarrow TP=19 \times FN$$

This gives us:

$$\frac{TP}{31.258}+\frac{TP}{19}=8 \rightarrow TP = 94.6$$

let's assume that means 95 true positive instances, so we get:

- $FP = 3$
- $FN = 5$
- $TN = 7$

Comment: This will only work for binary classifier. For multi-class just metrics are not enough.

Comment: @PiotrRarus-ReinstateMonica good point, I added it in my answer

Comment: in addition to `micro`/`macro` modes there's also `weighted` mode.